# Find a Windows-1252 char in mysql column

Tags: sql, mysql, character-encoding

There's a row that I believe contains a Windows-1252 smart-quote char in a particular column that is messing up a user of this table. How can I select any row that contains any Windows-1252 punctuation in this column?

AND it would be really cool if I had a way of converting these values if I redefine the column as being utf8 (it's currently latin1).

Answer (score 0):

The table structure already defines which charset is used in each column. So if you have a column using Windows-1252, then every text inside will be using Windows-1252. I would recomment changing the encoduing of your columns explicitly (easily done with phpMyAdmin).

Comment: Nope, it's declared latin1, and I can definitely see bytes that are illegal in latin1

Comment: latin1 is cp1252 is windows-1252 they're the same thing, and that's the most permissive encoding, any sort of characters is a valid code point.

Comment: Windows-1252 is a superset of Latin-1 "iffers from the IANA's ISO-8859-1 by adding additional characters in the 80 to 9F (hex) range (the ISO standards reserve this range for control characters). Notable additional characters include curly quotation marks and all printable characters from ISO 8859-15"

Answer (score -1):

Use `charset=iso-8859-1` no MySQL.